# Git: how to have log show only tags that match a pattern?

Tags: git, git-log, git-tag

I'm trying to list tags and hashes on a branch when the tag matches a specific pattern.

I have a command that looks like:

```
git log develop --tags="develop*" --remove-empty --pretty="%h %D" --decorate=short --decorate-refs=tags
```

I assumed the above will print for me a list of commit hashes with tags that match the pattern `"develop*"` (e.g. `develop_001`). But I still get commits with tags that don't match the pattern (e.g. `feature/*`). I'm including a snapshot from the output I get:

[image: git log output]

Additionally, is there a way to get rid of the commits that are not tagged?

Comment: The `--remove-empty`, by the way, makes no sense here. It only applies to `git log` commands that are doing history simplification by path-names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to list tags then don'tuse `git log` which lists commits. Just use something listing tags like this:

```
git tag --format="%(objectname:short) %(refname:short)" --merged develop  "v18*"
```

Here `--format`gives you the hash+tag output, `-merged develop` restricts the output to tags being ancestors of the `develop` branch and `v18*` ist an additional filter for tags matching that pattern.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to specify how to order the results. The output of the command above is: `31b53188d develop_001 ,937b1553 develop_002`, I know of `--sort=<key>` but I don't know how to indicate date, or decending order.

Comment: You can use sort-keys like `v:refname`, `creatordate`, `authordate` and so on. They are explained in the manual pages for `git tag`  and `git for-each-ref`.

Comment: So you can sort on data contained in a tag or commit. But you cannot sort on the order of commits.

Answer (score 1):

The job for `git log`, in general, is to *walk the commit graph*.  There are specific cases where you tell it not to do that, and your case is one of these specific cases.

To tell `git log` *not* to walk the commit graph, use `--no-walk`.  (Or use one of the other options that suppresses commit graph walking, but here, `--no-walk` is the right flag.)

Note that you probably also want *not* to tell it to start from `develop`.  The general idea (which, again, you will be telling it *not* to do) is that you give `git log` some starting commit or set of commits.  It locates those commits, then locates each parent commit of each of those commits, then the parents of those parents, and so on.  As it works, it prints out commits that it has not yet visited, then visits their parents.

Each of the *positive references* (as Git calls them) that you name, such as `develop` or `--tags="develop*"` acts as a *starting point*.  Git will show *that* commit, and then do the graph-walking / parent-finding.

Adding `--no-walk` stops the parent-finding, so that `git log` shows just the starting commits.